# Magento 2 admin system configuration add dynamic row with category chooser

Tags: magento2.4.3

I want to save the two-column in a system configuration with dynamic row 1 as a single select and second as a multi-select category chooser. Would you please provide me with the solution for it? I have attached the image for the same[[image]]